# Generics: Error referencing a type parameter in a non-static context

Tags: java, generics

```
public class stackofints<Item>
{
    private static node topofstack=null;

    private static class node{
        Item item;
        node next;
    }

    public static void push(Item item){
        node oldtopofstack=topofstack;
        topofstack=new node();
        topofstack.item=item;
        topofstack.next=oldtopofstack;
    }
    public static int pop(){
        Item item=topofstack.item;
        topofstack=topofstack.next;
        return item;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){return topofstack==null;}
    public static Item size(){
        Item i=0;
        node iterate=topofstack;
        while(iterate!=null)
        {
            iterate=iterate.next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        push(1);
        push(2);
        push(3);
        System.out.println(size());

    }

}
```

In the above code I am trying to use generic type but I get a compilation error:

> `File: D:\Java Code\stackofints.java  [line: 6]`
>   `Error: non-static type variable Item cannot be referenced from a static context.`

Can somebody help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: It is not a problem with generics but a problem of static/non-static access

Comment: You should follow the naming conventions.

Comment: Remove `<Item>` from class declaration. It is not necessary

Comment: `public class stackofints<Item>` is not  appropriate. Better would be `public StackOfInteger extends Stack<Integer>`

Comment: @SME_Dev Actually, it is. But it has no sense.

Comment: @SME_Dev It does not follow the naming convention and has no sense but it is syntactically correct.

Comment: `StackOfIntegers` and `Node` makes more sense as far as naming goes.

Comment: Advice : Extract the class `node` and put its code in a proper `*.java` file. It should be easier to undertand where the error comes from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: @UwePlonus: Not necessarily an exact duplicate. This issue has to deal with referencing a generic type parameter in a static context.

Answer (score 1):

Your class declares a type variable named "Item". It is not the name of a class, but only a placeholder allowing instances of the `stackofints` class to replace it with any type they want.

(As a sidenote, it is bad style to name those type variables ("placeholders") as if they were classes, because it is confusing. You should name it something like `T` instead : `class stackofints<T>`. Also, please name your classes in Camel-case, with an uppercase first letter : `class StackOfInts<T>`)

For example, you could have those instances :

```
stackofints<Integer> foo = new stackofints<>();  // Here, "Item" = Integer
stackofints<String>  bar = new stackofints<>();  // Now,  "Item" = String
```

So you see that the value of "Item" is specific to each instance, not to the class itself.

Now, you are trying to refer to this value from a static field. By definition, a static field belongs to the class itself, not to a specific instance.

That is why the compiler complains : you are trying to refer uniquely to something that can have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Generics in Java != Templates, you cannot do what you try to do in a static class. During runtime whatever `Item` was will be reduced to `Object` thus there cannot be a static instance of `T` in `MyType<T>` and a resolution of said instance during runtime (since every `T` is reduced to `Object`).

Solution: make everything instanced (non-static) and a singleton of your type.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, generics allow a type to be plugged when instantiating an object, and then can ensure that all future uses of the object use the object correctly.

Prior to generics:  List myList = new ArrayList();
                    Integer i = (Integer) myList.get(1);

With generics:  List myList = new ArrayList<>();
                Integer i = myList.get(1);

Without generics, there's a lot of casting and a lot of ClassCastExceptions at runtime; with generics, you wouldn't make it past compilation.

With your code, you're trying to use the generic in static methods.  However, static methods don't require object instantiation, and therefore have no context.  I can create a List, List, List, the static method would have no idea which to use, hence it's illegal.

Also, the design of this class, with essentially nothing but static methods, seems suspect, and you might want to revisit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error you are receiving deals with attempting to associate your type parameter `Item` that is bound to your `stackofints` class. This type parameter is only allowed to be reference in a non-static context. You need to define a type parameter in your `node` class. These names should be different to avoid confusion.

Now, there are a couple things wrong with your code.

1. Your `topofstack` variable should be an instance variable, so it should not be declared static.
2. Your `push`, `pop`, and `size` methods should not be static as they should be asscociated with an instance of a `stackofints` object.
3. You do not create an instance of `stackofints` in your main method.
4. You do not provide a generic type for your `node` class.
5. The `size()` method should always returns an `int`, the generic type does not matter.
6. By not adhering to Java syntax standards, you are making it difficult for others to interpret your code.

This code below is the correct way to accomplish what your are trying to achieve.

```
public class NodeStack<T> {
    private Node<T> topOfStack = null;

    private static class Node<I> {
        I item;
        Node<I> next;
    }

    public void push(T item) {
        Node<T> oldTopOfStack = topOfStack;
        topOfStack = new Node<T>();
        topOfStack.item = item;
        topOfStack.next = oldTopOfStack;
    }

    public T pop() {
        T item = topOfStack.item;
        topOfStack = topOfStack.next;
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return topOfStack == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        int i = 0;
        Node<T> iterate = topOfStack;
        while (iterate != null) {
            iterate = iterate.next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeStack<Integer> stackOfIntegers = new NodeStack<Integer>();
        stackOfIntegers.push(1);
        stackOfIntegers.push(2);
        stackOfIntegers.push(3);
        System.out.println(stackOfIntegers.size());
    }
}
```